# timezone in argo workflow

Tags: workflow, argo

timezone is not working in argo workflow.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: testing-wf
spec:
  schedule: "59 22 * * *"
  timezone: "US/Pacific"
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 0
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: main
    templates:
      - name : main
      ...
      .....
```

Not able to set timezone in argo workflow